# Converting text to mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, direct3d, freetype, glyph

I need to convert text (string+font) into mesh (vertices, indices, triangles etc), but I don't need to draw anything. I'll just get a string from one API and push it as vertices & indices to another. What's the simplest/easiest/best way of doing this? Font metrics and text placing are of course available and no other transforms are needed.

I'm currently working with VC++. However, any kind of OpenSource (C/C++, C#, VB,...) and "non-open but free" COM/.NET -libraries would be great.

I've heard of FreeType. Does it answer my prayers or is there something even better?

EDIT: As Nico Schertler commented, there seems to be Mesh.TextFromFont -function in DirectX -libs that probably does the trick. Thank you Nico! I'll update when I have time to test this in practise.

Comment: Uhm, an answer is not possible. You would need to provide some documentation of the text-format you parse, at least.

Comment: I can do pretty much any conversion from C++'s basetype char* to Java's StringBuffer. That's not an issue. I need a "mesher" that can make a mesh out of character/string using some defined font. Again, the font-object type is not an issue, conversions are usually trivial.

Comment: I use freetype and have found it pretty easy, but haven't touched the [vector data](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-6.html). Does anyone know of a library that can convert the curves to line segments and then fill the shape with triangles? Perhaps a fun exercise but time consuming to do yourself. **edit** I just found [this](http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/docs/html/ftgl-tutorial.html), but you said you didn't want the renderer bit.

Comment: There is a method in Managed DirectX that does this: [Mesh.TextFromFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb296610(v=vs.85).aspx). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo: Ah, you are looking for a _text mesh_, not some loader for model-data like 3DS or VRML; my mistake.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you! That seems simple enough for my case and, if I understood the doc correctly, covers everything I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesh.TextFromFont sounded good but it didn't save the day since I couldn't figure out how to get the actual point/triangle data from the mesh -object.

But then I found [this](http://www.dupuis.me/node/17). In this project, GraphicsPath is used to create a point-path from a glyph. Then the points are coverted into Polygons and the polygons are then tesselated into triangles using [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/).

A quick browse through the source code and with some small modifications and code stripping I ended up with a nice .NET -dll with one simple static function that does everything I need.

Comment: Have you shared this anywhere?

Comment: @joon Unfortunately I don't have the source anymore, but I do remember that changes I had to make to the Laurent Dupuis's project were quite minimal.

Answer (score -1):

To convert a text into a mesh you can use the [ttf2mesh](https://github.com/fetisov/ttf2mesh) library. This library consists of just one C-file and allows to open truetype font (.ttf) and convert it glyphs to a mesh objects in 2d or 3d space. There is an [examples](https://github.com/fetisov/ttf2mesh/tree/master/examples/src) in the repository.
An interesting feature is the lack of dependency on any third party library (like libfreetype). Also in the examples there is a ttf2obj program that allows you to convert a font file to an OBJ file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).